# Multiple results into one SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database and when I grab some results I want to work out how to return in a different format to what  I am getting now for example

```
select 
    reports.host_ip, reportitems.mskb 
from 
    reportitems 
inner join
    reports on reports.report_id = reportitems.report_id 
where
    reportitems.mskb IS NOT NULL 
order by 
    reportitems.mskb;
```

Output:

```
10.63.128.115|2251481
10.63.128.89|2269637
10.63.128.100|2269637
10.63.128.16|2269637
10.63.128.115|2269637
10.63.128.115|2669970
10.63.128.89|2871997
10.63.128.100|2871997
10.63.128.16|2871997
10.63.128.115|2871997
10.63.128.194|3000483
10.63.128.198|3000483
10.63.128.89|3000483
```

I would like the output to be for example all of the ips in the left column to be grouped so for 2269637 it would look like

```
10.63.128.89   
10.63.128.100        2269637
10.63.128.16
10.63.128.115
```

can I do that with the SQL statement or will i need to process that afterwards?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by grouped - your sample output isn't expressible as a data structure or a SQL table? What language are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this would be left up to the UI displaying the data, but if that isn't an option, or it's just difficult to implement, you could use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function and shove a carriage return in between values:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(reports.host_ip, '\n')) as IP_Addresses,
    reportitems.mskb
FROM reportitems
INNER JOIN reports
    ON reports.report_id = reportitems.report_id
WHERE reportitems.mskb IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY reportitems.mskb
ORDER BY reportitems.mskb
```